# can a vertex be both part of independent set and minimum vertex cover

Tags: graph-theory

Given an edge in a graph G, both ends cannot be part of independent set and both ends(vertices of edge) can not be part of minimum vertex cover set.

But can 1 end vertex be both independent set and also in minimum vertex cover.

In my textbook there is a theorem that if S is minimum vertex cover then its complement is independent set. I understood the proof. But i am not able to get clue why a single vertex be part of both independent set and minimum vertex cover.

Comment: Consider either node of $K_2$.

Comment: understood. Tq. sir pls see my 2nd comment below answer

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can: Let $G$ be any complete bipartite graph with the same number of vertices on each side. Then either side is both a minimum vertex cover and a [maximum-sized] independent set.

Actually, even if $G$ has more vertices on one side than another, the side with the most vertices is both a minimum vertex cover and a [maximum-sized] independent set.

Comment: Sir In first part, i understood that there can be some vertex both part of min vertex cover and max independent set. But theorem says if S is indepdennt set then its complement is min vertex civer. Does it mean their intersection NULL? which means there should not be any common vertex?

Comment: SIr in second part, should side with less num of vertices be min vertex cover and more num of vertices be max indepedent set?(we need vertex civer to be min and independent set to be maximum). Pls correct if i am thinking wronglyy. I am a beginner in graph theory

Comment: Sir kindly reply

Comment: @NascimentodeCos, yes, the smaller side is the unique minimum vertex cover, both sides are independent sets, and the larger side is the unique maximum independent set.

Comment: @RobPratt thank you sir....